# Как изменить язык во всем приложении программно, сразу?

Tags: android

Как изменить язык во всем приложении программно?

Данный код почему то не меняет язык в приложени он меняет лишь в текщем активити.

```
  public void changeLanguageApp(){
        SharedPrefHelper sharedPrefHelper=new SharedPrefHelper(context);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            conf.setLocale(new Locale( sharedPrefHelper.getUserLanguage() )); // API 17+ only.
        }
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }
```

Как сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопку приложение изменило язык?

В моем случае переключение работат лишь при след. запуске

Comment: мб в роли контекста взять getApplicationContext() - метод активити

Comment: СМОТРИТЕ. Меняться меняется. Но Интерйфейс изменяется лишь тогда когда я приложение заново перезапушу. А мне хочется чтобы как в Стандартном андроиде было. Тобишь выбрал язык и язык изменился

Comment: СКАЖИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА. Как изменить язык на арабский чтобы RTL тоже работал. Тобишь иконки и значки тожзе переворачивались

Comment: в layout у вьюшек есть характеристики left/right  поменяйте их на аналогичные но start\end - учитывает особенности языков. Т.е. если включен арабский, то кнопка перевернется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй выполнить этот код в главной Activity

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    config.setLocale(locale);
    createConfigurationContext(config);
} else {
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Артем. Но мне надо чтобы сразу язык поменялся. А не после перезапуска приложения